# Vlookup or index/match to match a value to the left side of the numbers in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, vlookup

I am trying to figure out a way of performing a vlookup for a given value. The value I am looking up in correct in its form (six character number). But the values in the column that i am trying to compare it against have some characters following the value that i am looking for. I was trying to figure out a way to implement the LEFT function on the lookup array in either Vlookup or Index/Match, but I havent gotten that to work. Is there any way to perform a lookup to only the left six characters in a column to return the desired information?

Answer (score 1):

Use a wild card:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1 & "*",B:C,2,FALSE)
```

This will find the first that matches on the left characters.

Comment: This worked a charm!!! Thank you so much!

Comment: FWIW, Index/match would work like: `=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(A1&"*",B:B,0))`